# How to get a text file to array. Using awk, each element separate on blank line

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a file containing many lines. I need to get these lines into an array. Each element of the array is split by empty line, it means each element of array may contain more than one line of text. Is there any solution using Awk?

I tried these:

```
myarr=($(awk -v RS= '{gsub(",\n",",")}1' compare1))
```

The problem is that each element is separated on new line, **not on empty line**.

How to reach these solution by using Awk? If there is another solution in Bash, it will be welcome as well.

Comment: if you don't mind using perl, following one-liner `perl -00p -F'\n' -e '$_="@F\n"' <<< $'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf'` is a beginning

Comment: Can you provide example of file you want to process?

Answer (score 2):

if we can asume there is no `\0` NUL character in the file, we can replace the empty lines with '\0', then use read to fill the array

```
readarray -t -d '' my_arr < <(  perl -00l0pe 1 compare1 )
```

and to check

```
typeset -p my_arr
```

EDIT: I just realized that

```
perl -00l0pe 1 compare1
```

could also be written with awk

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\0' 1  compare1
```

Comment: `readarray -t -d '' my_arr < <(perl -00l0pe 1 compare1)` avoids a loop.

Comment: @Shawn, that's true, updated, however it's still inefficient because of bash's read, would be better to work with perl, without knowing what the OP wanted after.